# how to transfer information in a array to a string? in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I would like to know to to move information from a array that looks like

```
i[0]=(
i[1]=9
i[2]=3
i[3]=5
i[4]=)
i[5]=3
.
.
.
```

in to another array to look like

```
j[0]=(935)3
```

I have tried and the only result I can get is a copy of the array with each character in a each element instead of all the character being in the first element.
code:

```
 char test[100];
    int n;
    int k;
    char i[16];
    n=0;
    char l[16];
    FILE *infile;
    infile=fopen(filename,"r");
    while( fscanf(infile,"%s",test)!=EOF){

       nums[n]=test;

    sscanf(test,"%s",&l);
        for(k=0;k<16;k++){
            i[k]=l[k];
        }
    n++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into multi-dimensional arrays as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is not STRING type variable in C, only an array of characters.
You can print them all together if you want with:

```
printf("%s\n",nameOfVariable);
```

But that is it, everything else you have to use characters.
Hope this helps you. :)